# Flutter TextFormField crashes the app when its focused

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a simple form in Flutter, however, I keep on running into an issue. Every time I tap on the `TextFormField`, the app crashes or kicks me out.

I don't even get the chance to type anything as the keyboard doesn't fully come up. I can see the keyboard quickly come up halfway and then I'm *kicked out*.

There is no error at all to help me debug. And Flutter doctor's result looks great. This happens in both the Flutter master channel and the stable channel as well (They are both upgraded to the latest versions).

I switched to the master channel in an effort to see if that would fix it but it did not. Would love some help.

**Flutter Doctor:**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.21.0-8.0.pre.176, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-US)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

**Code:**

```
class RegisterDeviceForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterDeviceFormState createState() => _RegisterDeviceFormState();
}

class _RegisterDeviceFormState extends State<RegisterDeviceForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "First Name",
                  ),
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Name is Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Last Name",
                  ),
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Last Name is Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ))); //Column // Form // Container
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it works really fine for me. Try to close your flutter app and restart your computer, and then try it again without opening any other app except your IDE and your emulator.

Comment: please post the error

Comment: No error occurs when this happens.

Comment: @AnnetteMaza Is this issue fixed? Please post the solution. So that it helps others.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tried a lot of approaches to fix this issue and none of them really worked for me. Later I found this issue only occurs in the latest android version. So, what I did was simple. I went to my app > find > build.gradle file and changed mine compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 33

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.